# Using struct and strcpy, program crashes

Tags: c, struct, printf, strcpy

Hello this is my first time posting on this site and also I am not very familiar with structures or with `strcpy()` I was wondering why my program below is crashing.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Employee{
    char name[30];
    char email[30];
};

void main(){
    struct Employee x;
    char employee_name[30];
    char employee_email[30];

    printf("enter the employees's name\n");
    fgets(employee_name,30,stdin);
    strcpy(x.name, employee_name);

    printf("enter the employee's email\n");
    fgets(employee_email,30,stdin);
    strcpy(x.email,employee_email);

    printf('%s',x.name);
    printf('%s',x.email);
}
```

The purpose of the program is basically to accept a name and email as input and put it in the name and email of the structure and than print them using the structure. Now the program compiles and allows me to take the input but after that it crashes and I do not know why. Does anyone know why the crash is occurring?

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with

```
printf('%s',x.name);
printf('%s',x.email);
```

as per the [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) format,

> `int printf(const char *format, ...);`

the fisrt argument is a `const char *`. So, you need to write

```
printf("%s",x.name);
printf("%s",x.email);
```

That said,

- `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least to conform to the standards.
- `fgets()` scans and stores the trailing newline (if any) to the input buffer as a part of the input. You may want to strip it off before copying the buffer.